# why dont i get any output

Tags: swift, class, object

hello there i am trying to create simple classes to get in the flow of information between classes in swift but here i can see no error no output . The playground is too amazed to analyse this man :')

```
import UIKit
class namesShape {
    var numberofSides : Int = 0
    var name : String
    init (name : String ){
    self.name = name
    }
    func simpleDescription() -> String{
    return "the shape name is : \(name) "
    }
}


class square :namesShape {

    var sideLength : Double
    init(name : String , sideLength : Double){
    self.sideLength = sideLength
    super.init (name: name)
    numberofSides  = 4
    }
    func area() -> Double{
    return sideLength*sideLength
    }

}



class triangle : namesShape {
    var sideLength : Int
    init(name :String , sideLength : Double){
    super.init ( name: name)
    self.sideLength =  sideLength
    numberofSides = 3
    }

}
let Square1 = square(name : "square1" , sideLength : 10)
println(Square1.area())
println(Square1.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- the variable `sideLength` in `triangle` is declared as `Int` but the `init` method has a `Double` parameter. Due to Swift's type safety the types must match.
- in `triangle` `super.init` must be called **after** initializing the variable `sideLength`

Here the full code with the recommended naming convention, variables and methods starting with a lowercase letter, classes, structs and enumerations starting with a capital letter.

```
import Foundation

class NamesShape {
  var numberofSides : Int = 0
  var name : String
  init(name : String) {
    self.name = name
  }
  func simpleDescription() -> String{
    return "the shape name is : \(name) "
  }
}


class Square : NamesShape {

  var sideLength : Double
  init(name : String , sideLength : Double) {
    self.sideLength = sideLength
    super.init(name: name)
    numberofSides  = 4
  }
  func area() -> Double{
    return sideLength * sideLength
  }
}

class Triangle : NamesShape {
  var sideLength : Double

  init(name : String, sideLength : Double) {
    self.sideLength =  sideLength
    super.init(name: name)
    numberofSides = 3
  }

}

let square1 = Square(name : "square1" , sideLength : 10)
print(square1.area())
print(square1.name)
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help . could u explain to me why does it matter for the triangle initiation to be after the sideLength . i mean , when i switch them it works but why ? :)

Comment: `init(name : String)` is the designated initializer of the class `NamesShape`. There is a rule (from the documentation): *A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.*